# Launch Screen Storyboard Image vs Launch Image Set

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, size-classes, ios-autolayout

When you use an asset catalog and a launch image, Apple provides all of the sizes you need in the launch image, image set:

[image]

It's a special category of image set. However, if you need to use a launch storyboard instead, you can't use that launch image, image set.

So, instead I create a normal image set and try to specify the images I need in there. However, it seems that the only time the images will show up during launch is when I choose universal.

[image]

[image]

When I switch the image to use iPhone specific devices, it doesn't render. Is there a way to make a normal image set work like the launch image set. I've tried choosing various width and height choices for the image set devices property.

[image]

Any ideas? Am I thinking about this the wrong way? I need to use a storyboard so just using the launch image isn't a valid answer.

Comment: I think the goal is to avoid device-sized images when using a launch screen storyboard. It negates the whole point of having one storyboard that works on all devices. Why not create your launch screen without large images? Add a label for the text. Give the background the needed green color. There should be a way to get the "sphere" using a normal, not screen-sized image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have thought about that as well, however, it doesn't look pixel perfect and since it's a white label app, the launch image is different for all targets--my customers all have their own separate assets catalog and launch image set. The screenshots I'm showing in the question are from a sample project I created just to prove out some theories. Thanks again.